# Xcode 5 won't start

Tags: xcode, osx-mavericks

I am having a lot of trouble getting Xcode to start, the app will lot load and respond, when I opened the Console app it gave this error `ERROR: attempt to move resize toolbar which is not shown, aborting _toolbarFrameSizeChanged:oldSize:`

I tried reinstalling it but it still has the same problem. What do i need to do to get Xcode working again?

Comment: Did you manage to get around this issue? Facing the same issue right now... :-(

Comment: never mind, just found the solution and posted it as an answer. :-)

Answer (score 4):

I did a lot of things, including un/re-installing Xcode, deleting preferences and application state, caches etc...

But the **only** thing that worked was deleting the 'Autosave Information' for Xcode.

```bsh
rm -rf ~/Library/Autosave\ Information/*.xcworkspace
rm ~/Library/Autosave\ Information/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
```

Comment: This also helped me today updating from Xcode 5 to 
Xcode 6 GM seed. The new version wouldn't open: it would bounce in the dock for a while, then stop, but no XCode windows would appear. After running that first command without even restarting Xcode, it started working; thanks!